# Is there equivalent of onbeforedeactivate event for Firefox etc.?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, dhtml

this works in IE

```
$('#blah').bind('beforedeactivate', fnBlah);
```

but I can not find equivalent for Firefox and other browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beforedeactivate` is an IE-specific event handler. The closest you can get are the `focusout` and `blur` events.

Usage in JQuery:

```
function eventHandler(){
    //...
};
$("element").focusout(eventHandler);
$("element").blur(eventHandler);
```

Links to JQuery implementations:

1. [Focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)
2. [Blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

Comment: focusout is almost right! here is an (old) plugin that tries to fix it: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/focus // it seems almost impossible to create robust UI using FF // IE is stronger in this regard // standards compliance is meaningless if the standards are low quality!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
object.addEventListener ("blur", handler, useCapture);
```

or

```
object.attachEvent ("onblur", handler);
```

found here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljjhfrjd.php

Comment: thanks for posting - there are big differences between blur and beforedeactivate! (1) beforedeactivate is cancellable (2) beforedeactivate bubbles AFAIK it is not possible to create robust UI using blur events alone

Comment: Sorry I misread the question as replacement,
You can check out [JS Ext](http://www.sencha.com/products/extcore/) for some great JS UI options, hope this is more helpful.
Good luck with your code!