# Chrome alternative for "onbeforedeactivate" event in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events

```
    if(_isIE){
        oBody.attachEvent("onbeforedeactivate", handleDeactivate);
    }else{
        oBody.addEventListener("beforedeactivate", handleDeactivate);
        
    }
```

"beforedeactivate" event is supported only in IE, not supported in Chrome. Could you suggest an alternative that is supported in chrome.

There are many answers out in stackoverflow suggesting "focusout" or "blur" as replacements. But foucsout/blur are much different from "onbeforedeactivate" event that is supported in IE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there equivalent of onbeforedeactivate event for Firefox etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514521/is-there-equivalent-of-onbeforedeactivate-event-for-firefox-etc)

Comment: @Reyno Thanks. I had seen that tag. Focusout/blur are only the closest events but dont behave exactly like the way "onbeforedeactivate" does in IE.